# Ajax code to access hidden or Non public html or php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using following Ajax javascript code to get response from another php page.

I below code, main page is sending request to mypage.php which is located in same directory and getting response.

But `mypage.php` page is accessible separately through `http:// ... /mypage.php`

I want to send request the non public files and get response `to prevent mypage.php access from http web access`.

say i want to access it from `/home/privatefolder/mypage.php` from ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkmypage(str)
{
//alert(str);
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("mypageResponse").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("mypageResponse").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","mypage.php?mypage="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**Note:** I know javascript cannot access non http:// files. please provide alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

Add request check at the top of your `mypage.php` and if true, include another php script from your `privatefolder` which does the jobs of `mypage.php`:

1- Check if request is an AJAX request or not in `mypage.php` :

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
  || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest') {
   // Not an AJAX request!
   header('Locate to an error page or other page');
   exit();
}
```

2- Include your script in else statement:

```
else {
   // $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is a good usage in here
   include('Path to your script in privatefolder');
}
```

Comment: Notworking! now mainpage.php is also going to `Locate to an error page or other page`

Comment: That's a comment, you need to put an actual location to your script in `header` and `include`, I'm not in your computer!

Comment: `// Not an AJAX request!`
Actually, i am sending ajax request from mainpage. it is not working. Both ajax and non ajax access is throwing same error. that is going to if condition

Comment: Did you put those at the top of your `mypage.php`. If call an ajax request to `mypage.php`, `header(...);` will be executed. Otherwise `include(...);` will be executed. If the process is not happening like this, you are doing something wrong because it's the way to know an AJAX request in php script which is generally told at Internet. And by _not working_ what do you mean actually? Did you put also script paths to `include` and `header`? Since I don't know your directory structure, I cannot tell anything about path string.

Comment: i tried printing the values in mypage.php `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];
echo strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']);` it returns empty value when accessed from mainpage.php and mypage.php

Comment: If your `mainpage.php` and `mypage.php` scripts are in same folder, write `header` function as `header('mainpage.php?test=1');` and after ajax request, check `test` is seen or not. If not, there is something very strange.

Comment: in which line or page you wanted me to write `header('mainpage.php?test=1');` ?

Comment: Inside `if`, replace with the `header...` in my answer.

Comment: I said, its always going to IF condition as both the values are empty when i echoed from both the pages... whats the purpose of doing this ?